# How to create a complex concurrent datastructure in rust

Tags: rust, concurrency

I need a struct containing several fields that should be usable in a concurrent context.

```
struct Foo {
    number: u32,
    collection: Vec<u32>,
}
```

In C I would add a Mutex to the struct and (un)lock that, but doing this in rust, using a `Mutex<()>` is not possible, as the struct is located somewhere inside an `Arc`. This means I need the `Mutex` around the fields if I want to mutate them.
However this leads to problems if I want to extract functionality into private methods, as `Mutex` is not reentrant.
[Edit]
If the fields in question are needed in both the main method and the helper method, locking multiple times is not the solution, as I would like the whole block to be treated as one unit, otherwise it would be possible to change something inbetween from another thread.
[/Edit]

In the simeple case like above, the solution would probably be to not make it concurrent at all and let the caller deal with it, i.e. use `Mutex<Foo>` and deal with the locking every time it is used.

However, in some situations, a `CondVar` is needed, to wait on the collection being filled or emptied, in which case I need a `MutexGuard` to wait on.
I guess I could move the `CondVar` to the outside as well, but then I would need to be concerned with the inner workings of my struct on the outside, which I don't like at all.

I don't know if I'm going completely into the wrong direction here, but I couldn't find anything on this by searching the web. Everything only talks about locking simple datatypes.

The approaches mentioned above:

```
struct Foo {
    lock: Mutex<()>,
    number: u32,
    collection: Vec<u32>,
}
```

```
struct Foo {
    number: Mutex<u32>,
    collection: Mutex<Vec<u32>>,
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn add_if_bigger(&self, v: u32) {
        let collection = self.collection.lock().unwrap();
        if self.is_bigger(v) {
            collection.push(v);
        }
    }

    fn is_bigger(&self) -> bool {
        let collection = self.collection.lock().unwrap();
        // already locked by this thread --^
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: in `add_if_bigger` why lock early and do double locking? Can't just do `self.collection.lock().unwrap().push(v)` i.e. one lock at a time

Comment: Because I want the whole method to execute as one block, as there can be more logic happening between the calls. Forgot to mention that. I will update the question.

Comment: Then I suggest remove lock from `is_bigger`, make it private. And for other threads have another wrapper public function `check_is_bigger` which will have the lock and will just call `is_bigger`. So no double locking.

Comment: Just make your functions take `&mut self`, then get rid of the mutexes inside the struct. I don't see why you have to use a mutex internally.

Comment: @Aplet123 Yeah, that was one idea, but what about the case where I need the `CondVar`?

Comment: @Abhijit-K `is_bigger` is already private, which changes nothing on the fact that I need to lock the fields inside it or how do you mean this?

Comment: Why can't you just use a mutex around the whole type? ie. `Arc<Mutex<Foo>>`